# core data with multiple NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation

Can I have a single Private Managed Object context that is being accessed by Multiple NSOperation ?

I have 2 two options :

1. Have a managed object context per NSOperation.
   i.e if there are 100 NSoperation 100 context will be created.
2. Have a single context and multiple NSOperation.

i.e Single Context and 100 NSOperations accessing it.

Which can be a better option.

Comment: What is the maxConcurrentOperationCount of your NSOperationQueue? Can your NSOperations be performed simultaneously? What is the amount of work that is done by single NSOperation (in amount of objects to be saved or in seconds to do its work)?

Comment: 1. maxConcurrentOperationCount is kept default currently. 
2. What is the amount of work that is done by single NSOperation :- A single object is fetched from core data compared with server object which ever objects wins then based on it a that object and file is uploaded or downloaded and written to disk.

Comment: As you described, you don't save a bunch of new data into CoreData in the single operation. So you can have single context and fetch any object from it. To avoid problems with concurrency you can use performAndWait function.

Comment: ok, thanks sander so you are suggesting I can go with 2 option.  Many people suggest going with option 1 including Marcus Zarra, That never share context between 2 thread and child context are cheap. Use them once, then throw them away. I felt that this is over-head since am working with single object at a time. Am still not able to decide a better solution. can anyone shade some light just in case I misunderstood

Comment: Ok, I'll post my answer below so that you can look at it closer.

Answer (score 0):

The correction solution is option 1.  Create a queue with a concurrency count of 1 and do all your writing with the queue.  This will avoid any write conflict which can lead to losing information.  If you need to access information for the main thread you should use a global main thread context (in NSPersistentContainer it is call `viewContext`).

If this is going to slow then you should investigate the work that you are doing.  Generally each operation should be pretty quick, so if you are finding that they are not you might be doing something wrong (a common issue is doing a fetch for each imported object - instead of one large fetch).  Another solution is to split up large tasks into several smaller task (importing large amount of data).  You can also set different priority - giving higher priority to actions that the user initiated.

You shouldn't  be afraid of creating contexts.  They are not that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said in the comments, that you didn't actually write lots of data in the single operation and just did a fetch for an object, I suggest using single `MOC`.

Usual reason to have multiple `MOC` is to read/update/save lots of data independently of `Main context` and of any other contexts. In such flow you would be able to save that objects concurrently from different contexts.

But it's not your case, If I understood correctly.

For the single fetch there would be enough just one `Private context`, however I believe there wouldn't be lots overhead in creating many contexts. But why to do extra work?

1.So, you create private MOC

```
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

2.Create each operation and pass MOC

```
let operation = MyOperation(context: privateContext)
```

3.In the operation perform sync call to private MOC with function.
In such way you should avoid any concurrent problem with single MOC

```
func performAndWait(_ block: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

for example

```
let myObject: Object?
privateContext.performAndWait {
     myObject = privateContext.fetch(...)
}
// do what you need with myObject
```